# Speed up code for serial protocols using bitbanging

Tags: c, serial-port, microcontroller, gpio, fastled

I'm wondering if there are any particularly fast ways to read or write a serial protocol (such as SPI) using GPIO calls (bitbanging) on a microcontroller.  What is fastest may be somewhat architecture-specific, but a smaller number of operations is likely to be faster on any architecture.  It is fair to assume port read/write and any bitwise integer operations happen in a single cpu clock; compare and jump may be a few clocks.

For a simple example, think of writing a byte using conventional SPI, given a port (register) with bitmasks for serial clock, miso (input), mosi (output) pins.  To output a 1 bit on the falling edge of the clock `port |= CLOCK|OUTPUT; port &= ~CLOCK;` and writing a byte would consist of doing this for every bit in that byte (outputting either 0 or 1), in a loop.

Something like this:

```
uint8_t data;
// for each bit, msb first
for (i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if ((data >> i) & 0x01)
    {
        // set output pin to 1
        port |= OUTPUT;
    }
    else
    {
        // set output pin to 0
        port &= ~OUTPUT;
    }
    // strobe clock
    port |= CLOCK;
    port &= ~CLOCK;
}
```

Some optimizations of this are obvious, eg unroll loops.

Some optimizations may be not so obvious: is it possible to switch based on the byte to be written (or just a part of it), and so avoid shifting and masking every bit?  How to make this branch free?  How to take advantage of runs of zeros or ones? (In which case there is no need to change the output, just the clock)  How about changing the output and clock in one operation?

An example that uses some of these tricks (change output and clock in one operation when possible, unroll loops, but not branch-free):
https://github.com/FastLED/FastLED/blob/master/fastspi_bitbang.h

Comment: Is your goal to find the maximum possible "SPI" clock rate you can get with your MCU?

Comment: How fast you can go entirely depends on what sits on the other end of the wire and the length of the wire.  The odds that this kind of code will work well are not that good, you almost always need to intentionally delay by spinning twice for a bit.  [This kind of config](http://dlnware.com/theory/Configurable-SPI-Delays) is normal.

Comment: @HansPassant: Good point.  The SPI device I have can handle 10MHz clock; this microcontroller can't produce a 10MHz clock in software even if it just toggles a pin back and forth.  The naive implementation of SPI in software runs around 300kHz :)  I can see how on a faster mcu and slower attached device, some delays may be needed.

Comment: @whitey04: In my case the attached device uses something a little bit different from SPI (it requires some other lines to be flipped at specific SPI clocks), so hardware SPI in the MCU cannot be used.  I think the limitation would be MCU speed not device speed since the MCU is really, really slow; my goal is to make it run as fast as possible on the MCU.

Comment: Alex & Hans...  If the MCU is "slow" you want to update the data bus as fast as you can with minimum # of opcodes.  If the MCU is "fast" you can use a HW timer interrupt and do other useful work instead of the busy wait to get the correct bus speed.

Comment: Don't think about the bus in terms of clock speed, instead look carefully at the setup and hold times for the attached device. These dictate the maximum speed and what parts of the waveform you can optimise out. If you really want to push the speed beyond a timer based implementation you will have to go to assembler though as relying on the compiler to produce a particular assembler construct is a great way to introduce the sort of intermittent timing violation bugs that take days to find when the compiler changes its mind in the future.

Answer (score 0):

SPI clocks the data every other edge.  Including an edge of the clock with your data is probably faster (same OR but saves one assign)

```
port = CLOCK
for (i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if ((data >> i) & 0x01)
    {
        // set output pin to 1
        port |= OUTPUT | CLOCK;
    }
    else
    {
        // set output pin to 0
        port &= OUTPUT;
        port |= CLOCK;
    }
    // strobe clock
    port &= ~CLOCK;
}
```

Comment: I think the code port &= ~OUTPUT | CLOCK; is not good ... because it means port = port & ((~OUTPUT) | CLOCK) that obtains the clock is set high only if it is already high ... :)

Comment: The clock is forced low at the bottom of the FOR loop; I'm assuming the data is clocked on the falling edge in this implementation.  I added an init to set the port & clock before the FOR loop starts (your code above would need something as well even if it doesn't set the clock).

Comment: Yes, but the CLOCK setting in the instruction into the else has no means because you are making a logic-and with the CLOCK set high, and then if port doesn't has the CLOCK bit already set high the CLOCK remains low!

Comment: Your right.  Code fixed; at least you get the freebie in the TRUE condition.